# Change colors based on categorical variable in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame of which I want to make a scatter plot and color code each point as either red or green based on the binary value of "Win" which is either 1 or 0. So far I have:

```
plt.title('Scatter plot')
plt.xlabel('blocked shots')
plt.ylabel('goals against')
plt.show()
```

but that returns a black and white graph

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is about `matplotlib` but have a look at [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html)'s `hue` parameter.

You code would end up looking something like this:

`sns.scatterplot(x='blocked_column', y='goals_column', data=df, hue='Win')`

Answer (score 0):

According to [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html)'s docs, you can use `c` argument to provide a sequence of colors for data points. All you need is to define a list of colors depending on the value in your `'Win'` column:

```
color = df['Win'].apply(lambda x: 'red' if x else 'green')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=color)
```